# Plot on the surface of a Torus

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, periodic-function

[image]I'm trying to plot a system with a variable (or field) $\theta(x,t)\in[-\pi,\pi]$ which is an angle at every position $x$. The positional argument $x$ itself is a periodic coordinate $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$. I'm trying to show some topological properties of this field, and I felt that a natural way to do so would be to plot the curve $\theta$ versus $x$ for $\theta = \theta(x)$ at a fixed time $t$ on the surface of a torus ($S^1\times S^1$). This would clearly represent the periodic nature of $\theta$ and $x$. Is there a neat way to do this on *Mathematica*?

For example, my idea was to use the blue coordinate (refer image) as the position variable $x$ and the red coordinate at each $x$ to represent $\theta(x)$. In this way both $x$ and $\theta$ are periodic.

Edit:
$t$ is time. I just put it there for completeness. I need to plot the variable at different time slices.

Comment: Maybe the word 'field' is a bit misleading. I just need to plot a function which has a periodic domain and range. For example, if I have a function \theta(x)=x, and x and theta are periodic. I wanted to use the toroidal angle for the variable x and the poloidal angle for theta.

Comment: (1) What's `t` in first line? How is that suppose to enter into the plot? (2) My take on your comment: You wish to plot a curve on the surface of $S^1 \times S^1$ that represents a function $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ given by $\theta = f(x)$?

Comment: Example  from your comment, $\theta = x$: `With[{f = Function[x, x]}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[\[Theta]]) Cos[
     x], (2 + Cos[\[Theta]]) Sin[x], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {x, -Pi, 
   Pi}, {\[Theta], -Pi, Pi}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x0, y0, z0, x, \[Theta]}, \[Theta] - 
      f[x]], #4 &, #5 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, ColorData[97][1]], Thin, Thin}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None]]` -- the thick, bluish line represents the graph, the thin lines are the $\theta,x$ axes. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be what I was looking for. However, when I tried slightly more general functions, the plot seems to be incomplete. For example \theta=2x seems to cutoff at some point, when it should wind around the torus twice.

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  I edited the question to try to clarify that the graph (curve) of $\theta(x)$ is what it being plotted on the torus. I do think the word "field" is misleading. To me it means a function that is defined at every point on the torus, either a scalar field or a (tangent) vector field. I left it in the question, but you might want to rephrase it. If I've messed up, feel free to roll back the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring $t$, which might seem irrelevant after some of the comments, one can plot $\theta = \theta(x)$ for $(x,\theta)\in S^1\times S^1$ with `ParametricPlot3D`. One issue is that some aspects of plotting functions do not automatically deal very well with discontinuities, such as `MeshFunctions`.  To make `x` periodic over $[\pi, \pi]$, one might use `Mod[#, 2 Pi, -Pi] &`, but it creates discontinuities that cause spurious mesh lines along the discontinuities.  Instead, consider the homeomorphism $S^1 \cong{\Bbb R}/(2\pi{\Bbb Z})$.  If $x,\theta \in S^1$, then we can use the subgroup $2\pi{\Bbb Z}$ for the `Mesh` specification.  However, a `Mesh` specification must be finite, so we need to know the bounds on $f(x)$ or otherwise specify a sufficiently broad range for `Mesh`.

```
With[{f = Function[x, 2 x]}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[θ]) Cos[x], (2 + Cos[θ]) Sin[x], Sin[θ]},
  {x, -Pi, Pi}, {θ, -Pi, Pi},
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x0, y0, z0, x, θ}, θ - f[x]], #4 &, #5 &},
  Mesh -> {2 Pi*Range[-10, 10], {0}, {0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Directive[Thick, ColorData[97][1]], Thin, Thin}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you probably need is: 
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceDensityPlot3D.html

and the equation(s) of a Torus is(are) given by:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html

Assuming that you want to work with (`u` as `x`) and (`v` as `t`), I guess you should try something like this:

```
\[Theta][u_, v_] := u + v;

c = 1; a = 4;
x = (c + a*Cos[v]) Cos[u];
y = (c + a*Cos[v]) Sin[u];
z = a*Sin[v];

SliceDensityPlot3D[\[Theta][u, 
  v], {(c - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2 + z^2 == a^2}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}]
```

Comment: This seems unlikely to be a convenient approach, since `SliceDensityPlot[]` plots in rectangular (x,y,z) coordinates and the field is given in circular/angular coordinates. Not sure why it was upvoted. Besides which the OP indicates three parameters $\theta,x,t$ to be plotted on a 2D surface generated by $\theta$ and $x$, the role of $t$ being unspecified. It's unclear what's being asked, so it's unclear how this is an answer. Again, not sure why it was upvoted.

Comment: I agree with you about the issue with 't' whose role is not being clearly specified by the OP but I disagree with you about the coordinates: Transforming angular coordinates into rectangular is not a problem at all (the second link I posted gives you an example).

Comment: I'm interpreting OP's question as follows:
He wants to use the (Azimuthal angle to represent x) and (The other angle to represent t), hence, he'll be able to plot theta(x,t) on a Torus using SliceDensityPlot[].

Comment: Well, that was close my original interpretation, too, although I thought the OP made it clear that the coordinates of the torus were to be $x$ and $\theta$, not $t$.; however, it didn't seem like the OP thought the code I posted solved the problem. -- As for convenience, one would have to get angular coordinates in terms of rectangular coordinates, which is not explained in the MathWorld page or in the answer. By inconvenient, I didn't mean unsolvable, though.

Comment: Okay, I just wrote the above, when you posted the new code.  What does your output look like? I get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UE9ei.png -- Is there a typo in the posted code?

Comment: It's just a guess. I don't have Mathematica 11 or above in this pc. I'll check it and edit my answer because I think that function requires those versions of mathematica.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86762/discussion-between-juanc97-and-michael-e2).